# Categorical variables of Int/Float types are lost when saving to parquet

Tags: pandas, pyarrow

I have the following dataframe in `pandas` that is saved as a parquet

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":['1','2','3']}).astype("category")
```

Upon inspection of the only field, we see

```
>>> df['a'].cat.categories
Index(['1', '2', '3'], dtype='object')
```

Now save and load the parquet file, and inspect the column:

```
>>> df.to_parquet("1.parquet")
>>> pd.read_parquet("1.parquet")['a']
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: a, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): ['1', '2', '3']
```

So far so good, everything behaves as expected, according to `categorical` data type documentation from both `pyarrow` and `pandas`, where both frameworks claim categorical data types are supported.

However, if we do the following(changing the source column type from `object` to `int`), then the categorical variable is lost either during loading or saving:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3]}).astype("category")
>>> df['a']
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: a, dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [1, 2, 3]
>>> df.to_parquet("1.parquet")
>>> pd.read_parquet("1.parquet")['a']
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Two questions:

1. Why are numerical-based categorical columns lost during this save/load routine?
2. Is there any way to prevent that from happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on [this tutorial](https://www.practicaldatascience.org/html/parquet.html) it seems like using [fastparquet](https://pypi.org/project/fastparquet/) engine will keep the categorical information:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3]}).astype("category")

df.to_parquet("1.parquet", engine='fastparquet')
pd.read_parquet("1.parquet", engine='fastparquet')['a']
```

gives me

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: a, dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert to string and then to category, this will preserve the category dtype after saving / reloading of the parquet

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3]}).astype(str).astype("category")
df.to_parquet("1.parquet")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly go through a `pyarrow.Table` object, types are maintained:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":['1','2','3']}).astype("category")
tab = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)

path = "/tmp/foo.parquet"
pq.write_table(tab, path)
df2 = pq.read_table(path).to_pandas()
df2['a']
```

returning

```py
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: a, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): ['1', '2', '3']
```

You can also use the `pa.dictionary()` type, though pandas support for that is very new.

Comment: That's the thing, for `object`(like `string`) it works right away. I gotta check if this approach still holds for non-string data types, like in the original post.